# A problem of Mathematica function with different parameters in the same model

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm simulating a graph of a function, and have made a preliminary attempt with mathematica, my test code is as follows:[image]:

```
Clear["`*"]
M = 1/2; a = 1; s = 1; intc = 5; L = 0; b = 1;
f[r_] = 1 - L - (2 M)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2];
rs[r_] = Integrate[1/f[r], r] - intc;
v[r_] = (1 - L - (2 M)/Sqrt[
     r^2 + a^2])*((b*(b + 1))/(r^2 + a^2) + (1 - 
        s)*((1/(r^2 + a^2)^(5/2)) (2*M*r^2 + 
          a^2 (-2 M - (-1 + L) \[Sqrt](r^2 + a^2)))));
V[r_] = v@InverseFunction[rs][r];
Plot[V[r], {r, -200, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

My results show that when $a=1$, I achieve the second one of Figure 1, [image], but when I test $a=0.99$, I failed. In principle, the same model only has different parameters. I don't know whether it is a problem of function setting. I would appreciate it if you could provide some help.

Another method of the test codes as follows,

```
Clear["`*"]
a = 0.99;
f[r_] = 1 - 1/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2];
ff[r_] = Integrate[1/f[r], r];
fid = OpenWrite["/Users/cc.csv"];
data = For[n = 1, n <= 2000, n++, rs = -250 + 0.25*n;
   M = 1/2; a = 0.99; s = 1; intc = 5; L = 0; b = 1;
   x = r /. NSolve[-intc + ff[r] - rs == 0, r, Reals][[1]];
   v = (1 - 
       L - (2 M)/
        Sqrt[x^2 + a^2])*((b*(b + 1))/(x^2 + a^2) + (1 - 
          s)*((1/(x^2 + a^2)^(5/2)) (2*M*x^2 + 
            a^2 (-2 M - (-1 + L) \[Sqrt](x^2 + a^2)))));
   Export[fid, List[{rs, v}], "CSV", "FieldSeparators" -> ","]];
Close[fid];

data = Import["/Users/cc.csv"];
ListPlot[{data[[1 ;; All]], data[[All ;; 1]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Joined -> True]
```

and the result is [image]

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I can't read your code because you are using `l = 1;` which makes it hard to read. Do not use lower case L for variable as it looks like 1. If you use different letter I can try to help.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have replaced the lowercase $l$ with $b$, and added a picture of the original code, hoping to give you a good read.

Comment: btw, you have to watch having integrate command taking `r` as argument and then integrating w.r.t. to that argument. If `r` is numerical, this will fail. The code you wrote can be re-written to avoid this problem coming into play. But I assume this is working for you so I did not change it. But I would not write it this way.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the possible solution to the problem. Physically, the parameter $a$ represents different physical backgrounds. The parameter $a$ can be divided into two parts, the cases of $a>=1$ and $0<a<1$. Currently, the test code I wrote is only applicable to $a>=1$. I don't know the reason for this. Before this, I used Matlab to complete the case of $0<a<1$ (the idea is to first discretize $rs$, replace the numerical result of $rs$ integral with an analytical expression, then solve inversely $r$, that is, $r[rs]$. Finally, substitute $r[rs]$ into $V[r]$). But in Mathematica, I failed.

Comment: If you have Matlab code that works for $a<1$, then why not just translate that code as is to Mathematica? This way you know it will work the same way. It should be easy to do the translation assuming your  did not use any special functions in Matlab which do not exist in Mathematica or something like this.  I can only use the code you provided and that gives problems with $a<1$, with Mathematica, it says the result is complex.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your attention and reply. After replying to the last message, I have implemented the translation of Matlab code into Mathematica, but the problem still exists. I'm not sure if this problem is due to the different calculation engines between these two (MAT and MMA). I've added new code to the question, but it seems to add a time cost.

Comment: Mabe you can also post the Matlab code below the Mathematica code. It is possible you made error in translation?

Answer (score 2):

When using Plot, it uses real numbers. For `a=0.99` the code you showed give complex numbers. Also it seems there are division by zero encountered. One option is to generate the data your self and use `ListPlot` instead and use `Abs`.

I used division of `1.0`. Notice that Plot uses adaptive divisions instead. But this way, we have avoided that problem.

```
Clear["`*"]
M = 1/2; a = 99/100; s = 1; intc = 5; L = 0; b = 1;
f[r_] = 1 - L - (2 M)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2];
rs[r_] = Integrate[1/f[r], r] - intc
v[r_] = (1 - 
     L - (2 M)/
      Sqrt[r^2 + a^2])*((b*(b + 1))/(r^2 + a^2) + (1 - 
        s)*((1/(r^2 + a^2)^(5/2)) (2*M*r^2 + 
          a^2 (-2 M - (-1 + L) \[Sqrt](r^2 + a^2)))));
V[r_?NumericQ] = v@InverseFunction[rs][r];
```

And now

```
data = Table[V[r], {r, -200, 20, .1}];
ListLinePlot[Abs@data, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Using a=0.99"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternative to the above is

```
Plot[Abs@V[N@r], {r, -200, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Using a=0.99"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is using `a=0.9` (need to change `a` at top)

```
Plot[Abs@V[N@r], {r, -200, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Using a=0.9"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is for `a=1`

```
Plot[Abs@V[N@r], {r, -200, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Using a=1"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the above plot for `a=0.99` does not match the one shown in the question. I do not know why, but that is what the code gives.